# Spring cloud DiscoveryClient. getLocalServiceInstance() deprecated, how to use Registration?

Tags: java, spring, microservices, spring-cloud, auto-registration

I have a requirement to get the current instance-id of the running microservice, the problem is that I have the requirement that if the process is not registered a "random generated" instance id has to be provided.

I'm trying to get the service instance id from the DiscoveryClient but as the code points out the `getLocalServiceInstance` is deprecated and I can't use it.

I tried to use the `Registration` as stated in the javadoc but coudn't find a way to get it initialized.

Is there a conventional/specific way to get a service own registration?

Btw, I cannot use a direct implementation because it is a starter that does not know what DiscoveryService implementation will be available at runtime.

```
/**
 * @deprecated use the {@link org.springframework.cloud.client.serviceregistry.Registration} bean instead
 *
 * @return ServiceInstance with information used to register the local service
 */
@Deprecated
ServiceInstance getLocalServiceInstance();
```

Comment: Yes, this is a problem I created that I plan to remedy soon.

Answer (score 2):

We can directly inject a `Registration` bean to do that, since class `Registration` is an abstraction, it should be adapted by different discovery clients, like if you are using Eureka, it will be an `EurekaRegistration` instance. For getting service instanceId, we can use the following code:

```
@Resource
private Registration serviceRegistration;

public Object someMethod() {
    //...
    String instanceId = serviceRegistration.getInstanceId();
    //...
}
```

we can also customize the `instanceId` by using `eureka.instance.instance-id` property in application.yml, see [spring eureka instanceId answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46206548/8108852)

Answer (score 0):

### Code

```
discoveryClient.getServices().forEach(id -> {
            discoveryClient.getInstances(id).forEach(instance -> {
                logger.info("/hello, host:" + instance.getHost() + ", service_id:" + instance.getServiceId());
            });
        });
```