# What is instanceid in spring eureka?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I read that instance id of Eureka Clients have to be unique and when we wish to run multiple instances of the same Eureka Client, then we add this property:

```
eureka.instance.instance-id==${spring.cloud.client.hostname}:${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
```

What is the significance of instance Id and how does the above line matter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is used to uniquely ID a single instance of multiple services E.g. if you deployed 2x instances of the same spring boot application the instance ID is used to distinguish between them.

Some additional use cases for PCF and AWS w/ Instance ID can be found in the documentation.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__service_discovery_eureka_clients.html

The above property simply takes the other properties, combines them. The only gotcha above is that if a `spring.application_instance_id` is not found in the environment it will use a `random.value` instead. You can override however you like but it should be unique.

Comment: I read that the default instance id is host:port. So if my instances are running on different ports, and hence have unique instance id's, then why do I need to edit the instance id like this?

Comment: you don't need to if you can guarantee that your applications will be running on different ports and the instance ID *will* be unique. When deploying onto something like PCF it will not be unique as the port will be set for each instance thus the instance IDs will clash.

Answer (score 16):

A Eureka Client has an **app ID** and an **instance ID**. T**he 
app ID is the name of the application while the instance ID is the unique id associated with the instance of the client**.

This helps **Eureka Server** to make a *distinction* between different client instances of the same application. In your example, the line shown below sets up a unique instance ID for your application having format: `<client host name>:<client app name>:<some random number>`

```
eureka.instance.instance-id==${spring.cloud.client.hostname}:${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
```

In my example shown below, the instance ID has the format - `<host name>:<app id>:<port>`.
The Eureka REST operation shown below will change the status of eureka client with app ID of `AUTHOR` and instance ID of `10.16.6.76:author:8766` to `OUT_OF_SERVICE`.

```
localhost:8761/eureka/apps/AUTHOR/10.16.6.76:author:8766/status?value=OUT_OF_SERVICE
```

If you noticed, Eureka Server can uniquely identify a client if you provide both the application ID and the instance ID.

[image]

Comment: this is great but how can i read this value from the application. I want to use it when i log to db